# ASP.NET MVC - Management

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Hey there, I'm trying to make a site which have following: News, Products, About and Contact. The problem is that for example the Products - I have an Index view to list the products for the user, but what if I want to make a "control panel" where I should be able to edit the products(names, prices, quantity) - how should that be done without have to create double productController?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have different views associated to one controller. Each view will be linked to an action method in your controller.

You could, for exemple, define your `ProductController` class like this

```
public class ProductController : Controller {
   [HttpGet]
   public ActionResult Index() {
      var productList = ProductService.GetProducts();
      return View( productList );
   }

   [HttpGet]
   public ActionResult Edit( int id ) {
      var product = ProductService.GetProduct( id );
      return View( product );
   }

   [HttpPost]
   public ActionResult Edit( ProductModel product ) {
      if (ModelState.IsValid()) {
         // save the changes
         return RedirectToAction( "Index" );
      }
      return View( product );
   }
}
```

And have the corresponding views in your `Views` folder :

```
Views
| -- Product
    | -- Index.aspx
    | -- Edit.aspx
```

Comment: Ah, must have been me there havent explained correctly. What I'm trying to is making a small CMS. You navigate to http://something.com/products and see the products listed. If you then go to http://panel.something.com and login you have a site where you can manage all of the pages for example the products. My question is should the panel and the normal site share controllers?

Comment: You would normally have different CRUD actions in the one controller. For the Create / Update / Delete actions, you just need to mark the action in the controller with the [Authorize] attribute to make sure a user is authorised to perform that action. http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/authenticating-users-with-forms-authentication-cs.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that Michael. The problem is that on http://panel.something.com/products - I want to be able to list the products once again but this time with Edit/Delete links. Should I create a new view for list in my panel or can I reuse the view that I have used for http://something.com/products ?

Comment: They seem to be different applications. You could go for the [Area](http://www.asp.net/learn/whitepapers/what-is-new-in-aspnet-mvc#_TOC3_2) approach, create a `Panel` area and use the same services.

Comment: My bad Bertrand, your first solution was perfect! - Thanks.